# Amazon data insertion

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with amazon services for insert images, video and audio data by using amazon ios sdk.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html

But unable to do so. I am following all the steps but could not understand how we are setting roles for user. Following is the error we are getting while uploading:

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSTSErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSSTSErrorDomain error 0.)" UserInfo=0x175673b0 {Type=Sender, Message=Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, __text=(
    "\n    ",
    "\n    ",
    "\n    ",
    "\n  "
), Code=AccessDenied}
```

Please provide your guidance regarding the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use [AWS IAM Console](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/modifying-role.html#role-edit-permissions-console) and add sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity Action with "Effect": "Allow" to your role.
Look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PoliciesOverview.html for examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough details in your question to help you, so let's make some assumptions first.

Based on the link you gave for documentation, I assume you are trying to upload file to S3 from an iOS mobile application.

How do you get credentials in your application?  I assume you are using Cognito Identity (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html)

Should my two assumptions be correct, a very common cause for your error message is a mistake in the Trust policy for your Cognito Role.

A Role has two parts, first the set of permission granted by this role.  Second a Trust Policy that describe who (or what) is authorised to assume this role.

For a Cognito Role with Authenticated users, the trust policy should be like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-1:12345678-abcd-abcd-abcd-123456790ab"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For instructions how to modify an existing role, please check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/modifying-role.html